# Most efficient way to multiply a boxed double by 2?

Tags: java, double, wrapper

Let's say we have a boxed double variable, `foo` and we want to multiply its value by `2` and store it in another boxed double variable , `bar`. From the following approaches,

**Approach One:**

```
Double bar = foo * 2;
```

and,

**Approach Two:**

```
Double bar = Double.valueOf(foo.doubleValue() * 2);
```

which one is more preferable considering efficiency, readability, and etc.? Or is the difference so trivial that these approaches are practically equivalent?

Comment: from readibility you can answer the question for yourself, from efficiency, that i asume depends on the implementation of the VM

Comment: The two should be equivalent, as autoboxing is compiled into a call to `valueOf`

Comment: @IanRoberts: Although often claimed, that is actually not required. The JLS only specifies that a primitive double p which is not NaN is converted "into a reference r of class and type Double, such that r.doubleValue() evaluates to p". The compiler may just as well use e.g. "new Double(p)" instead of "Double.valueOf(p)" and still adhere to the JLS.

Comment: @jarnbjo true in principle, but [not in practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14282533/592139).

Comment: @IanRoberts: So if mishadoff's car is black, all cars are black?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one. It has better readability and keep all boxing/unboxing operations behind the scene.

Do not think about efficiency of such simple operation as *multiplying by 2*.

...or long answer

Have two methods:

```
void method1() {
    Double foo = 1.0;
    Double bar = foo * 2;
}

void method2() {
    Double foo = 1.0;
    Double bar = Double.valueOf(foo.doubleValue() * 2);
}
```

Compile with `javac` and look bytecode instructions with `javap`

```
void method1();
   Code:
      0: dconst_1
      1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
      4: astore_1
      5: aload_1
      6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Double.doubleValue:()D
      9: ldc2_w        #4                  // double 2.0d
     12: dmul
     13: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
     16: astore_2
     17: return

 void method2();
   Code:
      0: dconst_1
      1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
      4: astore_1
      5: aload_1
      6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Double.doubleValue:()D
      9: ldc2_w        #4                  // double 2.0d
     12: dmul
     13: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
     16: astore_2
     17: return
```

Can you spot the difference?

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment to the question, the boxing conversion is implementation specific. If you don't see a difference in the output of your compiler, does not mean that my compiler does the same.

Answer (score 6):

Approach one is better.

- It can be read by humans
- All else being equal, fewer characters is better than more characters
- The compiler will probably remove any performance difference.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with points 1 and 3. These are probably the first things that should pop into your head before undertaking any optimisation.

Answer (score 4):

I think that no matter how you try to optimize it, java will make this version `Double bar = foo * 2;` at least as optimized as your solution. Trying to gain performance like that is usually fruitless.

Comment: I know this type of micro-optimization is fruitless..I'm just asking out of curiosity!